In Apache superset, Issue facing for setting the x-axis tile margin
I have installed the latest Apache superset version and created some dashvoards using posgresql data. I have used pie charts, bar charts etc. But right now i can't able to set the x axis margin parameter. Nothing is happen, while i'm changing the margin.
The margin should be effected on x axis.
